Dipole transitions between He states
An exercise, given some years ago at an exam here in Rome, asked to find the effect of a weak magnetic field on the transitions between the following states of helium at $T=0$ kelvin, in dipole approximation:
$${}^1S_0\to{}^1P_1
\quad\text{and}\quad 
{}^3S_1\to{}^3P_1$$
In the solution (see figure below) a total of nine possible transitions are given, three for the singlet  case (left) and six for the triplet case (right).
I don't understand why the $M_J=0\to M_J=0$ transition is not considered in the
${}^3S_1\to{}^3P_1$ case. Which selection rule is used here?


From the NIST webpage one of the selection rules is:

$\Delta M_J =0 , \pm1$, except transitions $ M_J = 0\rightarrow0$ when $\Delta J=0$

And in the described case of $P_1 \rightarrow S_1$ the $\Delta J$ is $0$, so the second part of the aforementioned rule comes into play forbidding $M_J=0\rightarrow0$.
